# Need Help in Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int mPosX,mPosY;//X & Y coordinates
    int mVelX,mVelY;//Velocity
    SDL_Rect *mColliders;//Dot's Collision Boxes
}dot;

void scale(SDL_Rect* r,size_t capacity)
{
    r=(SDL_Rect*)calloc(capacity,sizeof(SDL_Rect));
}
void rescale(SDL_Rect* r,size_t newcapacity)
{
    r=(SDL_Rect*)realloc(r,sizeof(SDL_Rect)*newcapacity);
}
void gc(SDL_Rect* r)
{
    free(r);
    r=NULL;
}


void dot_init(dot *d,int x,int y)
{
    //Initialize the Offsets
    d->mPosX=x;
    d->mPosY=y;
    scale(d->mColliders,11);
    //Initialize the velocity
    d->mVelX=0;
    d->mVelY=0;
```

The `SDL_Rectis` a structure and Contains fields like `x`,`y`,`w`,`h` 
all int. Now how to access those fields?

Ex. Something Like

```
d->mColliders[2].h=1;
d->mColliders[3].w=16;//This ain't working
```

I am very confused

Comment: `This ain't working` what does it mean? Not compiling (then post compiler error), crashing upon execution (then use a debugger).

Comment: I want to access the h field somehow!!!

Comment: Also, This ain't working here refers to Segmentation Fault !

Comment: Must be because `d->mColliders` was not set correctly, see my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this:

```
void scale(SDL_Rect* r,size_t capacity)
{
    r=(SDL_Rect*)calloc(capacity,sizeof(SDL_Rect));
}

void dot_init(dot *d,int x,int y)
{
    //Initialize the Offsets
    d->mPosX=x;
    d->mPosY=y;

    d->mColliders = NULL;
    scale(d->mColliders,11);
    // here d->mColliders is still NULL
}
```

after `scale`is called, `d->mColliders` remains `NULL` because the way pointer is passed to the function makes it only be modified locally.

See and run a minimal example illustrating this here: https://ideone.com/rIjoOC

You should write (requires C++):

```
void scale(SDL_Rect*& r,size_t capacity) // not the reference to pointer with &
{
    r=(SDL_Rect*)calloc(capacity,sizeof(SDL_Rect));
}

void dot_init(dot *d,int x,int y)
{
    //Initialize the Offsets
    d->mPosX=x;
    d->mPosY=y;

    d->mColliders = NULL;
    scale(d->mColliders,11);
    // here d->mColliders is not NULL
}
```

In C, use double pointers rather than reference, then do:

```
void scale(SDL_Rect** r,size_t capacity)
{
    *r=(SDL_Rect*)calloc(capacity,sizeof(SDL_Rect));
}

void dot_init(dot *d,int x,int y)
{
    //Initialize the Offsets
    d->mPosX=x;
    d->mPosY=y;

    d->mColliders = NULL;
    scale(&(d->mColliders),11);
    // here d->mColliders is not NULL
}
```

Or (works both with C and C++):

```
SDL_Rect* scale(size_t capacity) // simply return the allocated array
{
    return (SDL_Rect*)calloc(capacity,sizeof(SDL_Rect));
}

void dot_init(dot *d,int x,int y)
{
    //Initialize the Offsets
    d->mPosX=x;
    d->mPosY=y;

    d->mColliders = NULL;
    d->mColliders = scale(11);
    // here d->mColliders is not NULL
}
```

Comment: I am Using C! No reference variables!

Comment: Then, just use the second possible solution, where `scale` returns the allocated memory, this works in C.

Comment: That's an alternative, I edited my post to mention it. But, I would recommend to use last solution (using `return`), not always applicable, but, when it is (and it is in your case) it's much easier and less error-prone

Comment: Am I accessing h rightly? d->mColliders[2].h=1;   in the init function

Comment: Yes you are, did you check the variable content with a debugger?

Comment: @Prototype: "I am Using C!" - but you tagged your question with both C and C++, so jpo38 tried to be helpful and answered for both languages. (Now this has been cleared up and I have removed that tag, maybe the C++ parts could be moved under the answer for C?)

Comment: @jpo38 Will surely do, but, currently can't because of credits!